# BASH shell script to quickly create and populate new test files

Tags: bash, scripting, for-loop

```
# for i in {1..5} do echo "New File $i" > file$i done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'
```

I tried the above single line script which failed with the error above. I'm trying to automate the process of typing:

```
echo "New File" > file1  
echo "New File" > file2  
echo "New File" > file3  
echo "New File" > file4  
echo "New File" > file5
```

I'm trying to do this without creating a script file such as below which works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash                                                                                                                                                                                       
for i in {1..5} 
  do  
    echo "New File $i" > file$i 
  done
```

This script works but I want to be able to do something like this on a single line from the command line.

I understand the problem has something to do with the redirection `>` to the file. I tried escaping the `>` redirection a few other things, and googling but I didn't come up with something which worked.

The reason I want to be able to do this in a single line on the cli is because I want to be able to keep changing the numbers and contents of files for testing and I'd prefer to just do it on the command line rather than editing a script file.

#### Update 1

I tried the command separators as suggested and got the error below:

```
# for i in {1..5} do ; echo "New File $i" > file$i ; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
```

#### Update 2

I did the command separators incorrectly above in Update 1.
Done with the command separators as they are in the answer below worked like a charm.

Comment: Please format your code properly (indent every code line by 4 spaces).  This will make your question easier to read and understand and improve your chances of getting a decent answer.

Comment: I've been wondering about this for a bit now. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need either a semi-colon or a new line *before* the `do` and *before* the `done`. You do not need one after the `do`, although it doesn't hurt.

#### Single line

```
for i in {1..5}; do echo "New File $i" > file$i; done
               ^                               ^
```

#### Multiple lines

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    echo "New File $i" > file$i
done

for i in {1..5}; do
    echo "New File $i" > file$i
done
```

Comment: "...although it doesn't hurt": I get an error message if I put an extra semicolon after the `do` (`for a in b; do; echo; done`: 
"-bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'")

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me, all you needed to do to your update 1 was to insert a command separator between the `for` and the `do`:

```
for i in {1..5} ; do echo "New File $i" >file$i ; done
```